# how to cache external javascript files?

Tags: javascript, php, http, caching

I have web site where i am loading 100 and more external javascript files. 
At this moment it is opening single http request for each file and it make vary slow the site.
I want to optimize and cache js files in my server and also i want to refresh cache every 10 hour.

Can any one suggest me what can i do ?

exactly i want to collect all files and gzip them but i cant collect them. there is complex javascript loading not from single or 2 3 domain there is more then 50 domain ...

And also i have try http://farhadi.ir/projects/smartoptimizer/ this but it is for internal files only

Comment: I thought April fool day was yesterday?

Comment: but rely it is vary complex question . it is old web site waited in pure php